# Image not aligning right

Tags: image, apache-flex

I have an image within a controlBarContainer that is not wanting to align right for some reason. My code looks like this:

```
<s:controlBarLayout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:controlBarLayout>
    <s:controlBarContent>
        <mx:Text color="#EC6500">
            <mx:htmlText>
                <![CDATA[
                <b><font size="18" font-weight="bold">Institut für Angewandte Geowissenschaften</font></b>
                <b><font size="12">Forschungsprojekte: Geo-Ressourcen und Geo-Risiken</font></b>
                ]]>
            </mx:htmlText>
        </mx:Text>
        <mx:Spacer width="100%"/>
        <s:Image height="100" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high"
                 source="@Embed(source='../images/logo.png')"/>
    </s:controlBarContent>
```

Is there any way I get the image to align right while aligning the text left?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you set the containers width (ControlBarContent) to 100%, youll get the desired alignment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but it had something to do with the image needing to be edited. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's already algn to reight, becuase the container is not wide enough, so you think it's not working.

Try modify the parent container to 100%:

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but it had something to do with the image needing to be edited. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what the issue was, but after messing around with the code for a bit, I noticed that there appeared to be an issue with the image. I imported the image into GIMP and resized it then saved it as a png and jpg. Both the png and jpg files seemed to embed just fine. If any has any theories as to what might have been going on, please let me know for the future.